# Calculating probability that you are dealt a full house

Tags: probability, poker

What is the probability that you are dealt a "full house"? (Three cards of one rank and two cards of another rank.)

why can't I calculate the probability in the following way?

The number of ways I can select 2 suits from one rank = $$13 \choose 2$$
The number of ways I can select 2 suits from one rank = $$4 \choose 2$$
The number of ways I can select 3 suits from another rank = $$4 \choose 3$$

so p should be $$\frac{{13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 3}}{52\choose5}$$

My question is how can I tweak my approach and reach the right answer.

Comment: What makes you think it's not the right answer?

Comment: the asnwer does not match the answer at answer page

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{13}{2}$ is not the right choice to make, because the two ranks you pick *do not have the same role* in the rest of the computations, so for example "sevens and queens" is a *different* choice at this stage than "queens and sevens".

Thus, instead of $\binom{13}{2}$ you should just use $13\cdot 12$ -- namely, one factor for the rank there'll be three of, then one factor for the rank there'll be two of.